# Find the transfer function and state space of the system

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, control-theory

Two separate experiments are performed for t ≥ 0 on the single-input single-output (SISO) linear system $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu, y = Cx + Du$, $x(0) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ (the initial condition is the same in each experiment)

In the first experiment, $u(t) = e^{-t}$ and the resulting output is y(t) = $e^{-3t} + e^{-2t}$

In the second, $u(t) = e^{-3t}$ and the resulting output is $y(t) = 3e^{-3t} − e^{-2t}$

(a) Can you determine the transfer function $C(sI−A)^{-1}$B+D from this information? If it is possible, do so. If not, find two linear systems consistent with all the data given which have different transfer functions.

(b) Can you determine A, B, C, or D?

i tried taking the laplace transform of each inputs and outputs :

$Y_1(s) = \frac{1}{s+3} + \frac{1}{s+2} , U_1(s) = \frac{1}{s+1}$

$Y_2(s) = \frac{3}{s+3} - \frac{1}{s+2} , U_2(s) = \frac{1}{s+3}$

from what i've known output is summation of the initial condition term and input term, so if the initial condition is non-zero.Is the transfer function of the system still $ \frac{Y(s)}{U{s}}$

Comment: This is obviously an exercise, so you will have to show your attempts first. Also, it is better to write down the full question here (and not use a picture) in case the link dies.

Comment: i'm really sorry, this is my first time posting. I already edited the post.

Comment: No problem. This is much better now.

Comment: No, when the initial conditions are nonzero, then you have that $Y(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}x_0+H(s)U(s)$ where $H(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B+D$. What you can do now, is expressing $Y_1(s)$ and $Y_2(s)$ and a build a system of linear equations in the "unknowns" $H(s)$ and $C(sI-A)^{-1}x_0$. Then, solve that and see what you get.

Comment: I tried thinking about it but don't really get how i can form the state space from Y(s) and does x(t) = [y1 dy1/dt y2]?

Comment: Answer first the first question. You'll see later for the state space form expression.

Comment: I've got $\begin{bmatrix}Y1(s)\\Y2(s)\\\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-H(s)}{s+1}+\frac{1}{s+2}+\frac{1}{s+3}\\\frac{-1}{s+2}+\frac{3-H(s)}{s+3}\\\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}H(s)&0\\0&H(s)\\\end{bmatrix}U(s)$ and then i set the inital condition term of two equations equal to each other to find H(s). Am i doing this correctly?

Comment: No, you need to write a system of two linear equations with the two unknowns $H(s)$ and $C(sI-A)^{-1}x_0$. If $X(s)=[H(s)\ C(sI-A)^{-1}x_0]^T$, then you will have $Y(s)=M(s)Xs)$ for some $M(s)$ that you will need to find and invert, if possible, to find the solution(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post a beginning of a solution to help OP, and I will complete it bit by bit.

So, we can write the following system of equations

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
Y_1(s)\\
Y_2(s)
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
U_1(s) & 1\\
U_2(s) & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
H(s)\\
G(s)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $H(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B+D$ and $G(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}x_0$. So, we get that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
H(s)\\
G(s)
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
U_1(s) & 1\\
U_2(s) & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
Y_1(s)\\
Y_2(s)
\end{bmatrix}=\dfrac{1}{U_1(s)-U_2(s)}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1\\
-U_2(s) & U_1(s)
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
Y_1(s)\\
Y_2(s)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then, the idea would be to see whether the transfer function is realizable, which means that $H(s)$ is rational and proper (i.e. the degree of the numerator is at most that of the denominator).

---

Edit. Construction of a possible realization for the $H(s)$ of order 3.

So, after some tedious algebra we get (as @nap also correctly obtained)

$$H(s)=\dfrac{s+1}{s+2}=1-\dfrac{1}{s+2}$$
and
$$G(s)=\dfrac{1}{s+3}.$$

Since, there is constant term in $H(s)$, we can put this in the direct feedthrough $D=1$, and then we get that $C(sI-A)^{-1}B=-1/(s+2)$.

The dimension of the system is 3 (from the initial condition), so the model will not be minimal and a mode will be uncontrollable and/or observable.

One way to build the system is to fix an eigenvalue of $A$ to be $-3$ and to build $A$ such that $x_0$ is an eigenvector. Similarly, we can set an eigenvalue to be -2 and to set $B$ to be an eigenvector (i.e. this eigenvalues is chosen this way because we need to have $s+2$ at the denominator in one way or another). So, we pick for instance,

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},$$

and note that this choice is completely arbitrary. We just need to make sure that $B$ is linearly independent of $x_0$. And we can just a last eigenvalue at random, say -1, and pick the eigenvector to be $(0,1,0)$ which is linearly independent of the others.

We can now build the matrix of eigenvectors

$$V=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\0 & 2 & 1\\0 & -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
which is associated with the diagonal matrix
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0 & 0\\0 & -3 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$ which is the diagonal form of $A$ in the basis $V$. We can now find $A$ using the expression $A=VDV^{-1}$ and we get

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 4\\
0& 0 & -3\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, we need to select $C$. To do so, we evaluate the following expressions

$$(sI-A)^{-1}x_0=\dfrac{1}{s+3}x_0$$
as expected and
$$(sI-A)^{-1}B=\dfrac{1}{s+2}B$$.

So, if we pick $C=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, we get that

$$C(sI-A)^{-1}B+D=1-\dfrac{1}{s+2}$$

and

$$C(sI-A)^{-1}x_0=\dfrac{1}{s+3}$$

as desired.

---

Update. What if the order of the system is 2. In this case, $H(s)$ and $G(s)$ remain the same but one can define now
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0\\0 & -3\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$V=\begin{bmatrix}b & x_0\end{bmatrix}$$

where $b$ must be such that $V$ is invertible; i.e. $b$ and $x_0$ are linearly independent. Then, the rest follows from the same lines as in the previous case.

Comment: Thanks, now i get $H(s) = \frac{s+1}{s+2}$ , $G(s) = \frac{1}{s+3}$.
I try to solve $H(s)=C(sI−A)^{−1}B + D$ and $G(s) = C(sI - A)^{-1}x_{0}$, but it doesn't seem to be possible to solve it directly to get A, B, C, D. Is there any other way?

Comment: Your expressions are correct. Now, the issue is how to interpret the second question. If the question is about the unique characterization of the matrices, then no, because the system is of order 3 (dimension of the initial condition) whereas the transfer function is of order 1, which means that some modes are uncontrollable, unobservable or both. If the goal is to find one possible solution for the matrices, then yes, you can, and there are infinitely many.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a possible way to find one possible realization as it is a bit complicated.

Comment: I'm curious that if H(s) is of order 2, can we use the same method?, like suppose H(s) = $1 -\frac{1}{(s+2)(s+1)}$, i will get $ \frac{-1}{(s+2)(s+3)} = C(\frac{1}{s+2})B$  which is  $ \frac{-1}{s+3} = CB$. Is there something wrong?

Comment: If the system is of order 2, $H(s)$ and $G(s)$ will remain exactly the same. The other matrices will have to be redesigned. I will update the answer.

Comment: sorry, i mean if i have a system that the transfer function is of 2nd order and $(sI-A)^{-1}B = \frac{1}{s+b}B$ where B is eigenvector and b is eigenvalue of A, if the transfer function is $\frac{1}{(s+a)(s+b)}$ and assume D is zero, i will get $\frac{1}{s+a} = CB$ but shouldn't CB be a constant?

Comment: No, if $H(s)$ is of order two and of the form you provide, then $B$ should be a vector in both the eigenspace of $-1$ and $-b$. You will need to do all the calculations from the beginning and not just try to fiddle around.

Comment: Thank you so much, i really appreciate you efforts.